# Unverified breakpoints on applying breakpoints in 'api' folder files but it's working for 'src' folder files

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, sails.js, vscode-debugger

This is my Visual Code setup. I am able to apply breakpoints in the src folder, but not in the api folder where my Sails.js controllers are located.

[image: See fig]

Comment: Try going to VSCode settings and search for "Debug: Allow Breakpoints Everywhere", if you enable that, it might fix it.

Comment: @Noitidart, On enabling this setting, Initially It is allowing to put debug point everywhere. But applied debug getting disable on debugging start.

Comment: Interesting, please keep me updated on a solution as I'm curious to debug like this too.